# Is it possible to display text at an angle in a web page?

Tags: html, css, text, angle

I would like to know whether it is possible or not to create text in a web page at an angle, for example at 40 Degrees. If it is possible, how can I do this?

EDIT: Finally, I decided to go with Mathias Bynens's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to Mathias' answer, you can rotate text in IE, too: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-text-rotation

However, you are bound to multiples of 90°.

Apart from that you could utilize SVG/VML for rotated text. Look, for example, at this page: http://raphaeljs.com/text-rotation.html

It uses the RaphaelJS library for cross browser text rotation without images.

Comment: There was already mentioned in Kyle’s answer and in the comments on mine, but yeah, you’re right :)

Comment: I saw them both when I saved the answer. You should include your comment back in your answer. Makes it a full 100% coverage one :-)

Comment: So the best soltuion is using that RaphaelJS library for Cross Browser Rotation? There isn't any easier way?

Comment: @Ryan: The *easiest* is an image. But of course, it's the least favourable. Apart from that it's mainly a mess to do it cross-browser, and, yes, I'd suggest RaphaelJS and a JavaScript solution, if you need it done quickly and don't need the ability to select text.

Answer (score 11):

Use CSS3 transforms:

```
.selector {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(40deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(40deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(40deg);
  transform: rotate(40deg);
}
```

IE does support `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);`, where the rotation property accepts one of four values: `0`, `1`, `2`, or `3` which will rotate the element 0, 90, 180 or 270 degrees respectively. It’s a filter though, so I wouldn’t recommended using it.

Comment: The OP should note that most versions of IE do not support CSS3

Comment: @Richard Good point. IE does support `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);`, where the `rotation` property accepts one of four values: `0`, `1`, `2`, or `3` which will rotate the element 0, 90, 180 or 270 degrees respectively. It’s a filter though, so I wouldn’t recommended using it.

Comment: Thanks very much all of you, I will try them out.

Answer (score 0):

Mathias is right in his answer, but to also support IE you can use their filter:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
/*play with the number to get it right*/
```

Then IE will be supported too :)

Comment: Unfortunately, as I noted in the comments on my answer, the rotation property will only accept four values: `0`, `1`, `2`, or `3` which will rotate the element 0, 90, 180 or 270 degrees respectively. There’s no way to do a 40° rotation this way.

Comment: Aha, really?  I never use the filter, just know about it so I didn't realise it was "fixed." Trust MS to invent something useful but at the same time _useless_.

Comment: It's a shame why IE tends to be so different (tedious) at times